# How to solve the problem of dead links to external clouds (blend files)?

Tags: discussion, blend-exchange

I'm beginning to realize that it's quite inconvenient when a (blend) file related to a question or answer is lost over time because it's no longer available.

External links that are outdated can be corrected under certain circumstances, but files that are essential to the question, such as blend files or images that are linked to external proprietary clouds and are then no longer available, can no longer be corrected.

Of course, from the user's point of view, it's convenient to be able to link any files from your own cloud, but I question the usefulness of that, especially since it could lose the long-term value of a question or answer.

Hence the crux of the question:

- Does it make sense to keep the ability to link any files in a question/answer?
- Would it be possible to disallow linking to specific files or clouds (at least in the questions and answers)?
- From a technical point of view, is there a way to integrate https://blend-exchange.com/ into the rich text editor so that there are fewer cases where essential information is missing from the start? ([Here](https://blend-exchange.com/userscript) is the proof that this is possible in principle, only can it be simplified and made available to all users?)

My goal would be to reduce the number of useless questions by creating policies that largely prevent dead links by not allowing links in the first place that may be dead at some point in the future.

PS: A user could of course always be so free despite such policies, and continue to post links to external clouds in the comments, but from my point of view it would make sense to at least keep questions and answers more restrictive.

Comment: It is untidy. I wonder what you think: how many of the questions ( as opposed to answers ) which depend on  linked .blend, or other files,  are of much searchable generality? How many of those are of much use to the archive a long time after being posted? Most often, those ones  seek a solution to a particular symptom without knowledge of the cause, and if there is any generality, it's in the answers.

Comment: @RobinBetts If these questions/answers are not relevant for the search and also have no long-term benefit, why are these questions not deleted right away? And yes, it would be great if the answers to these individual questions/problems would always turn out to be generally valid. After all (or in the long run), it's always just about being found and creating a collection of knowledge, or am I wrong?

Comment: @RobinBetts And there are answers that have become obsolete due to the constant development of Blender (*Geometry Nodes*, for example). Only unfortunately, the original Blend file is then often missing to be able to give a contemporary and correct answer to it. I think therefore that it can be a problem in a way if this original information is not preserved. ...for example. Or am I looking at this too narrowly?

Comment: @RobinBetts Take [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283179/) as an example. Without the Blend file, it would have been impossible to provide a meaningful (or satisfactory) answer. And again, it has not been possible for me to provide a universal answer. From my point of view, the whole post would have no use in the long run if this information was not available, and could not be reconstructed on the basis of a concrete example.

Comment: 'Why not deleted straight away'?   Yes, I guess I was hinting at  a purge, there, but not on..?.  Policy pretty hard / impossible to define, destructive of accumulated rep. That question: (Nice answer BTW)  After some time has passed, I guess I'm suggesting that the .blend in the question is no longer so useful. The .blend in the answer is, for a much longer time.

Comment: I agree with you. It would be very good, especially with an edit-tool, to guide .blend links to blend-exchange on BSE, in the same way as images are guided to stack.imgur,  SE-wide. Rarely, it's necessary to exceed blend-exchange's size limits. Those could be from comments.

Comment: Some of this as been discussed before https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/look-at-my-file-via-pasteall-or-others-and-answer-me-the-good-way-now I have strong feelings about files in posts, I rarely include any in my answers at all for other reasons. I think all posts should stand on their own without the need for downloading a file, save for some questions where recreating an issue can be time consuming.

Comment: Answers that rely on a file downloading are as far as I'm concerned poor answers, and most questions that require downloading a file are in my opinion too localized and should be closed. Of course I won't enforce this more strict view and have relaxed the rules a bit, people should be able to get their answers, otherwise this would be a desolate site. But I still think it makes them a low value questions in the long term.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I completely agree with you in both comments, actually. However, this is (as you know, I don't know other topics that well) often hardly possible with Geometry Nodes without knowing the exact setup. Rebuilding is often too uncertain. In answers, on the other hand, I tend to consistently supply the blend file for the same reasons (Even if the answer would basically do without blend file). Strictly speaking, most geometry node questions are very localized (70%?) and without a blend file the question would remain open forever because no one wants to bother rebuilding it all.

Comment: I agree that questions only answerable with access to the blend files should be avoided if possible, which is already up to our discretion with the "too localized" flag. My suggestion for cases where this isn't easily possible, such as e.g. geometry nodes projects, would be to encourage adding the relevant information that were needed from the blend-file to the question after an answer was written and accepted or that this information is included in the answer. Both would help to understand the underlying issue and also help with discoverability.